# Ubiquiti UniFi Video

Tags: 14.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and have what is probably an easy answer question please.
I am trying to install a software package from Ubiquiti Networks. It is a network video NVR software program. Ubiquiti have an installer for Ubuntu V 14.04 which i have downloaded and installed on my V14.04 PC. It is showing up in the Ubuntu software centre as installed with the green tick but i can't for the life of me figure out how to run it?

Assistance required pretty please :)

PS. this is a link to the software packages for this product (there are 3 versions of Ubuntu 64bit supported)
http://www.ubnt.com/download/?group=unifi-video-camera

Thanks muchly
Matthew

Comment: What's the name of the mentioned software package and how did you install it? You can [edit] your question to improve it and include additional info.

Comment: Could you post the output of the following commands: `dpkg -L unifi-video_3.0.8~Ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb` and `dpkg -s unifi-video_3.0.8~Ubuntu14.04_amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Start a browser on your Ubuntu computer and log into http://localhost:7080 or https://localhost:7443 for HTTPS access.